# Whats the other way to write this code? Any shortcuts in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My first week with SQL, and in class, we are going over some tasks. Can you suggest how to eliminate time by writing this code a little bit shorter (if possible).

> TASK: Best Customers Per Employee
>
> Create a query that retrieves the total sales to each customer who spent more than $5,000 by each employee (Hint: use the Order Subtotals query already in the database). The result should be sorted ascending for employee last name and then the total descending within each employee.

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, CompanyName, 
cast(Sum((unitprice-(unitprice*discount))*quantity)as decimal (18,2)) AS SumOfSubtotal
FROM Orders

JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = [Orders].OrderID
JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID  

GROUP BY Customers.CompanyName, Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
HAVING SUM((UnitPrice-(UnitPrice*discount))*Quantity) > 5000
ORDER BY Employees.LastName, SUM((UnitPrice-(UnitPrice*discount))*Quantity) DESC
```

Comment: yes, you can use aliases for table names

Comment: 'Order Subtotals query already in the database' what does this look like?

Comment: You'd probably get more appropriate help if you tagged the question properly; MySQL does not use `[` `]` for delimiting identifiers.

Comment: it says that we have order sub, but actually we have to come up with the formula ourselves

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.) PS What does "eliminate time" mean? What exactly does "writing this code a little bit shorter" mean & why do you care? What exactly is your question? PS Please do not ask for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Do the allies like Customers c  Orders o Employee e Order Details od.

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, CompanyName, 
cast(Sum((unitprice-(unitprice*discount))*quantity)as decimal (18,2)) AS SumOfSubtotal
FROM Orders O

JOIN Customers C ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
JOIN [Order Details] OD ON OD.OrderID = O.OrderID
JOIN Employees E ON O.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID  

GROUP BY C.CompanyName, E.EmployeeID, E.LastName, E.FirstName
HAVING SUM((UnitPrice-(UnitPrice*discount))*Quantity) > 5000
ORDER BY E.LastName, SUM((UnitPrice-(UnitPrice*discount))*Quantity) DESC
```

Comment: how exactly would you input that? I'm sorry for dumb and easy questions but the struggle is real :)

Comment: @MaximBushko I edited your code so it looks smaller

Comment: @MaximBushko What do you mean, "how exactly would you input that?" (By typing? Cut & paste? By translating to MySQL or the DMBS SQL you are actually using?) Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.--In your posts & comments.